# Use sed to remove part of Outputfile

Tags: bash, shell, sed

I have following output in a file which is generated through another set of commands.

```
 3   ReplicationFactor3  Conf.ms=126543
 3   ReplicationFactor3  Conf.ms=139875
```

I need to remove words **ReplicationFactor** and **Conf.ms** from this file. I use following sed command but it only remove **Conf.ms**.

```
 sed -r -i 's/\b('ReplicationFactor'|Configsretention.ms=)\b//g' file.txt
```

Much appreciate if someone can help on removing **ReplicationFactor** from this output file.

Comment: What is the expected result? Try `sed -r -i 's/\b(ReplicationFactor|Conf\.ms=)//g file.txt'`, see [this demo](https://ideone.com/fRVB3Y).

Comment: There is no word boundary between `ReplicationFactor` and `3` as both `r` and `3` belong to the `\w` "word-character" character class, which is composed of `[A-Za-z0-9_]` (`a_1A8__1` is a single word, however weird it seems). You will need to rely on another factor to identify the specific occurences of `ReplicationFactor` you need to remove.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$> cat file.txt
 3   ReplicationFactor3  Conf.ms=126543
 3   ReplicationFactor3  Conf.ms=139875
$> sed -i 's#ReplicationFactor##;s#Conf.ms##' file.txt
$> cat file.txt
 3   3  =126543
 3   3  =139875
```

Comment: thank you Frank, This actually does the work, how can I remove = sign. I tried adding = sign at the end but didn't work. Also I would like to get a clarification on this command if time permits.

Comment: `sed -i 's#ReplicationFactor##;s#Conf.ms=##' file.txt` works for me to strip the = sign.  Is it really the equal sign what you see?  You can check with `od -ctx1 file.txt`.  Or try 's#ReplicationFactor##;s#Conf.ms.##' the dot removes any character

Comment: it was issue in my output file. Your solution working perfectly. Thaank you for your time and consideration on this matter.

Answer (score -1):

try in this way. `'ReplicationFactor'` is needed to be `ReplicationFactor`

```
sed -r -i 's/\b(ReplicationFactor|Conf.ms=)\b//g' file.txt,
```